# Filter for a value in objects nested in an object

Tags: javascript, object

How would I go about filtering through the object `listOfPeople` to see if an email existing within an object inside of it? For example, does there exist an object within `listOfPeople` where email: **"d@fj.s"**.

```
listOfPeople = {
0: {referred: Array(0), _id: "5e177e40f3f68644b72e1f14", email: "e@w.f", __v: 0}
1: {referred: Array(0), _id: "5e147e90f3f61644b72e1f75", email: "d@ds.d", __v: 0}
2: {referred: Array(0), _id: "5e177eb2f3f68344b72e1f76", email: "d@fj.s", __v: 0}
3: {referred: Array(0), _id: "5e172f32f3f48644b74e1f77", email: "j@dfhgh.cg", __v: 0}
4: {referred: Array(0), _id: "5e177f46f3f68444b72e1f78", email: "jhvg@df.cg", __v: 0}
5: {referred: Array(0), _id: "5e1781baf3f68214b72e1f79", email: "test@rest.com", __v: 0}
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] (include JavaScript)

Comment: why not take an array and filter this?

Comment: @NinaScholz The text above is a response from an API and it is in the form of an object

Comment: what result do you expect? a boolean or the filterd items?

Comment: You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of your keys - then use `filter` and iterate the array of keys and check the object.

Comment: @NinaScholz Boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the values and check the value.

```js
var listOfPeople = { 0: { referred: [], _id: "5e177e40f3f68644b72e1f14", email: "e@w.f", __v: 0 }, 1: { referred: [], _id: "5e147e90f3f61644b72e1f75", email: "d@ds.d", __v: 0 }, 2: { referred: [], _id: "5e177eb2f3f68344b72e1f76", email: "d@fj.s", __v: 0 }, 3: { referred: [], _id: "5e172f32f3f48644b74e1f77", email: "j@dfhgh.cg", __v: 0 }, 4: { referred: [], _id: "5e177f46f3f68444b72e1f78", email: "jhvg@df.cg", __v: 0 }, 5: { referred: [], _id: "5e1781baf3f68214b72e1f79", email: "test@rest.com", __v: 0 } },
    find = "d@fj.s",
    result = Object.values(listOfPeople).some(({ email }) => email === find);

console.log(result);
```